# Cannot find "/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" in ag-grid-community

Tags: ag-grid

My AG Grid application is now failing to load styles from `https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css` with the error:

```
Cannot find "/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" in ag-grid-community@29.0.0
```

This used to work before the v29 release.

Answer (score 7):

The v29 [Changelog](https://ag-grid.com/changelog/) describes why this dist folder has been deleted and the styles have been moved to a new location.

To resolve please follow the [instructions](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-upgrading-to-v28-css/) from the official docs as the styles are now in a new location.

```
<!-- old path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community@28.0.0/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" />

<!-- new path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community@29.0.0/styles/ag-grid.css" />
```

Comment: You might have to put ag-grid-community/styles in package.json if you don't already have it